# python insert into list at constant x position

Tags: python, list, position, constants

I know by the title this may sound easy. It's not for this task.

Imagine the following scenerio: you have a connection running, and a list called example. You get some data with a constant number x that will *always* start with 1 and increase then on until the connection is closed. You need some data surrounding this number and it to be stored in a list at exactly that number's position. so `example[x-1]`. Ok, so this solves the basic problem.

The problem this doesn't solve is, say if that the connection gives you a command to delete some of the data previously stored as it's no longer needed. Let's say at this point, you have 10 item's in the list, you need to delete at positions 3, 5, and 6. So now, example is at 7. x is now 11, you insert some data, and now `example`'s length is at 8. At this point, `exmaple[x-1] != 11`. So now, we have fragmentation.

The problem is this. The connection will (but not in a set order) give you some other data. This data will also have the same number as `x`, but we'll say it's `y`. This data need's to go together (let's just say `x` and `y` are int's that need to be added for purposes of this example, though we're really filling in missing stuff in a class). but at a later point in the data sequence, but you now no longer have x-1 to put the 2 parts of data together. The problem now is that because you're not able to set `example[x]` and *ALWAYS* have it *EXACTLY* at position `x` in `example`, there's now no way in run-time to match both positions `x` and `y`.

My question is, is there some way like in C++ how you can do `example[x] = data;` and it will always be no matter what in position `x` dependent on what's changed around in the list, such as removing items. If this isn't possible, then I'll put efforts into calculating a formula for the position of the `example` list so that it can always match.

Comment: yeah make it a dict instead of a list ...

Comment: alternatively, OP can reassign items to `None` instead of deleting

Comment: @JoranBeasley your comment clarified a question, I was completely lost on third paragraph

Comment: if your running this thing for 30 days, i'd say that's quite inefficient for ram usage.

Comment: what? cellsheet what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
example = {}
example[1] = "whatever"
example[99] = "whatever"
example[-12] = "something else"
example['cow'] = 'pie'
#delete
example.pop(99)
```

is that what you are looking for?

or

```
example = [0 for _ in range(MAX_ITEMS)]
#delete
example[x-1] = 0
#add
example[x-1] = data
```

Comment: the first one and that it's guarentee'd that that statement will always be true no matter what's been taken in our out of `example` for later reference in run-time.

Comment: I dont understand your comment ... but sure

Comment: @cellsheet It's probably overkill (but you did mention running for 30 days), but you can always use http://redis.io/ which'd have the advantage of being accessible outside of your Python process, fast key looks and deletion, some handy basic structures, and if you wanted expiry of keys after a certain time...

Comment: yeah sorry for my wordyness. but if you run that code, wouldn't `example[99]` be empty since from my earlier experience it would move it to `example[2]`?

Comment: ummm no ... it is dictionary keys ... they stay .. a quick warning though ... dictionaries do not have order

Comment: heh, somehow forgot about dictionary's holding more than 1 key to value pair. Thanks though